# Is there a way to return the value of the environment variable RAILS_ENV from the Linux command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, environment-variables, environment

In Linux, you can find the value of the `$PATH` environment variable with the command `echo $PATH`. In Rails, `RAILS_ENV` (and the similar `RACK_ENV`) is an environment variable with values such as "development" and "production". But on the command line, `echo RAILS_ENV` returns the unhelpful string `RAILS_ENV` (as you'd expect) and `echo $RAILS_ENV` returns nothing (presumably because that's not what the environment variable is called). I've also tried `env RAILS_ENV` and variants. Am I getting the syntax wrong, or what?

Am I right to think that basically the environment variable just doesn't exist until Rails is run? Well...I tried running a Rails server in one terminal, then opened another and then repeated the above commands; no dice.

Or is the problem that Linux, or my shell, doesn't track this environment variable? But...wouldn't it have to, being an environment variable? I tried looking for it in the output of the `env` command, and it's not there.

Is it possible that the only way to discover the value of the `RAILS_ENV` environmental variable is through Rails itself, e.g., by calling `Rails.env`?

UPDATE: [this helpful discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249399/how-to-check-rails-environment) gives the command `rails r "puts Rails.env"`, but I was looking for a command that didn't call Rails itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right with `echo $RAILS_ENV`. It is likely not set, so it is defaulting to development. This is done within the Rails codebase.

```
$ export RAILS_ENV=development
$ echo $RAILS_ENV #=> development
```

In another console

```
# In a new window
$ echo $RAILS_ENV
$ rails runner "puts Rails.env" #=> development
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails runner "puts Rails.env" #=> test
```

No `RAILS_ENV` variable is set, to rails defaults to development

Here is the equivilent in Bash.

```
if [ -z "$RAILS_ENV" ]; then
  export RAILS_ENV="development";
fi
echo $RAILS_ENV
```

Comment: So `rails r "puts Rails.env"` works because it runs Rails, and then finds the environment variable (that you set before) from within that process?

So, basically, the environment variable is not pre-loaded into the environment before Rails is run (say, when Rails is originally installed), although you can pre-load it yourself if you want?

So can I discover (from the command line) the environment of a currently-running instance of Rails (such as the server running in another terminal)?

Comment: I.e., can I discover (using Bash commands) the environment of a currently-running instance of Rails? I'm just surprised that it doesn't show up in the output of `printenv` unless I use `export RAILS_ENV=development` (or `test`; `production` doesn't work) in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer to split up the examples. Rails defaults to development when no RAILS_ENV is set. Any other environment (test, production) will have the RAILS_ENV set.

Comment: Here is where rails sets the default of development as the env. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/railties/lib/rails.rb#L73

Comment: Thanks. Still curious why `printenv` doesn't show the variable if it's been set in a running process, though.